# How to setup a bootable Linux USB live stick?

Tags: linux, debian, usb-flash-drive, liveusb

I like to setup a 4 GB USB stick to act like a bootable media that boot a small debian lxde environment. Everything should be editable so there is no special persistent section (it all is).

How to acceive this? What is the workflow? What are the tools? I checked out various live usb installer but all do have their persistent partition.

After I have done the setup I like to make an img from the USB stick to clone it on other USB sticks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean about persistance? Why do you need everything to be editable? What exacly are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Hi @terdon. Most (or all) live usb installers install the os complete write protected and let the users save their data to an seperate (very small) partition. My setup should be 100% writable because a normal os installation is. I like to update packages or read the log from a previous boot which I can't if is not persistent. I want a normal os on a usb stick like on a normal computer with a hdd.

Comment: OK, so you _want_ it persistent. I had understood that you did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for http://www.pendrivelinux.com/. The site has all the information you need, I recommend you have a look at it. The following is what [they suggest](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/making-ubuntu-710-casper-persistent/) for installing a persistent Ubuntu 7.10 :

1. Download Ubuntu 7.10 (Gutsy Gibbon) and burn to a CD/DVD
2. Restart your PC from the CD/DVD
3. Open a terminal and type sudo su (to become root)
4. Type `mkdir /projectinit` (to make our project directory)
5. Type `cd /projectinit` (to change to the project directory)
6. Type `gzip -dc /cdrom/casper/initrd.gz` | cpio -i (to extract the initrd.gz)
7. Type `gedit init` (to edit the init file)
8. From `gedit`, find the following section:

   ```
   break)
   break=premount
   ;;
   esac
   ```

   Directly above `esac` add the following:

   ```
   persistent)
   PERSISTENT=yes
   root_persistence=casper-rw
   home_persistence=home-rw
   ;;
   ```

   It should end up up like the following:

   ```
   break)
   break=premount
   ;;

   persistent)
   PERSISTENT=yes
   root_persistence=casper-rw
   home_persistence=home-rw
   ;;

   esac
   ```
9. Save the changes to update the init file
10. Type `find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip -9 > initrd.gz` (to zip the new initrd.gz file)
11. Then you can copy the new `initrd.gz` file to your usb flash drive, replacing the old file (or rebuild the iso to include the new file)

To boot persistently, at the boot menu press F6 to enter a custom boot option. Add persistent to the end of the boot string:

[image]

I cannot guarantee that this will work for a recent Debian but it should be a good starting point. Even if it doesn't you should be able to find all the information you need on the pendrive linux page.

Good luck!